# get the Adapter reference inside onlick listner for the listview header button

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I've a list view with a header. There is a 'Go' button in the list header. And for its on click I need to call a custom method in the Custom Adapter. How can I get the Adapter reference in side onlick lister?

```
public class GroupListActivity extends ListActivity {
...
private void createGroupList() {

    final ListView listView = getListView();

    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.multi_list_groups_header, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(view, null, true);
    TextView listHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.groupsHeader);
    Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);

    this.gAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this, R.layout.multi_list_groups2, gStore, true);
    this.setListAdapter(this.gAdapter);
    //listView.setFocusable(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Manual Go!!");
            // I need to call the adapters' getCheckedItems() method here
        }
    });
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Group> {
    ...
    public HashMap<String, String> getCheckedItems() {
        return checkedItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to create a custom `Button` that holds on to a reference of your `GroupAdapter`.  That way, you can cast the passed in `View` object to your custom `Button`, and then get your `GroupAdapter`.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Manual Go!!");
        Map<String, String> checkedItems = ((MyButton)v).getGroupAdapter().getCheckedItems();
    }
```

Comment: How can I have the reference of an Adapter in custom button?

Comment: If you define the constructor to take in the Adapter, then you can hold on to its reference.